# Testing once condition in Golang

Tags: go, testing, concurrency

I've got a module that relies on populating a cache with a call to an external service like so:

```
func (provider *Cache) GetItem(productId string, skuId string, itemType string) (*Item, error) {

    // First, create the key we'll use to uniquely identify the item
    key := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", productId, skuId)

    // Now, attempt to get the concurrency control associated with the item key
    // If we couldn't find it then create one and add it to the map
    var once *sync.Once
    if entry, ok := provider.lockMap.Load(key); ok {
        once = entry.(*sync.Once)
    } else {
        once = &sync.Once{}
        provider.lockMap.Store(key, once)
    }

    // Now, use the concurrency control to attempt to request the item
    // but only once. Channel any errors that occur
    cErr := make(chan error, 1)
    once.Do(func() {

        // We didn't find the item in the cache so we'll have to get it from the partner-center
        item, err := provider.client.GetItem(productId, skuId)
        if err != nil {
            cErr <- err
            return
        }

        // Add the item to the cache
        provider.cache.Store(key, &item)
    })

    // Attempt to read an error from the channel; if we get one then return it
    // Otherwise, pull the item out of the cache. We have to use the select here because this is
    // the only way to attempt to read from a channel without it blocking
    var sku interface{}
    select {
    case err, ok := <-cErr:
        if ok {
            return nil, err
        }
    default:
        item, _ = provider.cache.Load(key)
    }

    // Now, pull out a reference to the item and return it
    return item.(*Item), nil
}
```

This method works as I expect it to. My problem is testing; specifically testing to ensure that the `GetItem` method is called only once for a given value of key. My test code is below:

```
var _ = Describe("Item Tests", func() {

    It("GetItem - Not cached, two concurrent requests - Client called once", func() {

        // setup cache

        // Setup a wait group so we can ensure both processes finish
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(2)

        // Fire off two concurrent requests for the same SKU
        go runRequest(&wg, cache)
        go runRequest(&wg, cache)
        wg.Wait()

        // Check the cache; it should have one value
        _, ok := cache.cache.Load("PID:SKUID")
        Expect(ok).Should(BeTrue())

        // The client should have only been requested once
        Expect(client.RequestCount).Should(Equal(1)) // FAILS HERE
    })
})

// Used for testing concurrency
func runRequest(wg *sync.WaitGroup, cache *SkuCache) {
    defer wg.Done()
    sku, err := cache.GetItem("PID", "SKUID", "fakeitem")
    Expect(err).ShouldNot(HaveOccurred())
}

type mockClient struct {
    RequestFails    bool
    RequestCount    int
    lock            sync.Mutex
}

func NewMockClient(requestFails bool) *mockClient {
    return &mockClient{
        RequestFails:    requestFails,
        RequestCount:    0,
        lock:            sync.Mutex{},
    }
}

func (client *mockClient) GetItem(productId string, skuId string) (item Item, err error) {
    defer GinkgoRecover()

    // If we want to simulate client failure then return an error here
    if client.RequestFails {
        err = fmt.Errorf("GetItem failed")
        return
    }

    // Sleep for 100ms so we can more accurately simulate the request latency
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)

    // Update the request count
    client.lock.Lock()
    client.RequestCount++
    client.lock.Unlock()

    item = Item{
        Id:              skuId,
        ProductId:       productId,
    }

    return
}
```

The problem I've been having is that occasionally this test will fail because the request count is 2 when it's expected it was 1, at the commented line. This failure is not consistent and I'm not quite sure how to debug this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your tests fail sometimes because your cache fails to provide guarantee that it only fetches items once, and you're lucky the tests caught this.

If an item is not in it, and 2 concurrent goroutines call `Cache.GetItem()` at the same time, it may happen that `lockMap.Load()` will report in both that the key is not in the map, both goroutines create a `sync.Once`, and both will store their own instance in the map (obviously only one–the latter–will remain in the map, but your cache does not check this).

Then the 2 goroutines both will call `client.GetItem()` because 2 separate `sync.Once` provides no synchronization. Only if the same `sync.Once` instance is used, only then there is guarantee that the function passed to `Once.Do()` is executed only once.

I think a `sync.Mutex` would be easier and more appropriate to avoid creating and using 2 `sync.Once` here.

Or since you're already using `sync.Map`, you may use the [`Map.LoadOrStore()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map.LoadOrStore) method: create a `sync.Once`, and pass that to `Map.LoadOrStore()`. If the key is already in the map, use the returned `sync.Once`. If the key is not in the map, your `sync.Once` will be stored in it and so you can use that. This will ensure no multiple concurrent goroutines can store multiple `sync.once` instances in it.

Something like this:

```
var once *sync.Once
if entry, loaded := provider.lockMap.LoadOrStore(key, once); loaded {
    // Was already in the map, use the loaded Once
    once = entry.(*sync.Once)
}
```

This solution is still not perfect: if 2 goroutines call `Cache.GetItem()` at the same time, only one will attempt to fetch the item from the client, but if that fails, only this goroutine will report the error, the other goroutine will not try to fetch the item from the client, but will load it from the map and you don't check whether loading succeeds. You should, and if it's not in the map, that means another, concurrent attempt failed to get it. And so you should report error then (and clear the `sync.Once`).

As you can see, it's getting more complicated. I stand by my earlier advice: using a `sync.Mutex` would be easier here.

Comment: I considered a `sync.Mutex` here but I need to call `cache.GetItem` once for each unique key, and I wasn't sure how to make a mutex work in that scenario. I'd really appreciate an example if you don't mind spending the extra time.

Comment: @Woody1193 The "best" solution depends on your other, unlisted requirements. E.g. Is it OK to block other `Cache.GetItem()` calls with different keys while an item is being fetched from the client? If an item is being fetched, other `Cache.GetItem()` calls with same key should wait? Or may return error? If wait, all calls should return the same error if getting it from the client fails? And what if in case of an error another `Cache.GetItem()` is issued? Should it retry? Or return the same old error again and again?

Comment: What I would like, is for each unique value of key that the method is called with, `client.GetItem` is called exactly once. Any other concurrent calls with the same key should wait until the `sync.once.Do` call is finished.

Comment: And what if that errors? All concurrent requests should return the same error? And future calls to the same key?

Comment: If `client.GetItems` fails then I would expect it to return an error but anything else should just return nil.